# listview item move to first animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

i want to move an listview item to the first one.

so i should move the item to (0,0) relative to the listview.

i use animation in xml like this

```
< translate android:duration="5000" android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="0%p"/ >
```

but it do not work.

`0%p` not means the beginning of the listview?

any help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: please share your code..

Answer (score 0):

Use should use .setSelection to go beginnig of list view,

**ListView.setSelection(0);**